# Zooming to specific location

Tags: anychart

I've included the world map and I'd like to know how I can zoom to a specific continent e.g. europe, without using coordinates.

I already found the .zoomTo method.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [version 7.12.0](http://anychart.com/products/anymap/history) there is no way to specify the set of regions to be zoomed too, but:

1) There is also [zoomToFeature](https://api.anychart.com/7.12.0/anychart.charts.Map#zoomToFeature) method  that allows zooming into a given feature;

2) and probably this way may work for you, changing:

```
        var mapScale = map.scale();

        mapScale.minimumX(100);
        mapScale.maximumX(153);
        mapScale.minimumY(-50);
        mapScale.maximumY(-10);
```

Here is [Sample of AnyMap zooming to Australia based on hit test and geo scale changes](http://jsfiddle.net/cgrLe7co/) based on this option. Zoom out must be done the same way too.

3) There are plans to allow zoomToFeature method to zoom to a set of features, probably version 7.13 or 7.14

Comment: Thanks! That works for me! :) Which values do I need to pass to zoom back to 100%?

Comment: @user2030592 you need to store initial min/maxs using the same methods as getters, note: you can use them as getters only after draw() method: http://jsfiddle.net/cgrLe7co/1/


    var mapScale = map.scale();

    initMinX = mapScale.minimumX();
    initMaxX = mapScale.maximumX();

    initMinY = mapScale.minimumY();
    initMaxY = mapScale.maximumY();

Comment: Thanks again for your reply! In general I think I do understand this now but when trying to add another continent i am getting relatively weird views. I've added a console.log to your hit variable to see the coordinates i am getting. Then I clicked on the upper left corner of a continent and on the lower right and extracted the min and max values. See this fiddle for South America: http://jsfiddle.net/mmintel/cgrLe7co/3/

Comment: Alright I think I figured it out and my problem was that I have to convert the coordinates like this here:var values = anyMap.globalToLocal(evt.clientX, evt.clientY);
      var pixels = anyMap.inverseTransform(values.x, values.y);